# Environmental variables in /etc/environment are not accessible by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu

I have been trying to deploy a rails project and it requires some environmental variables so I did some research and it turns out the best place to add them is inside /etc/environment which i did so and then sourced the file. 
I now can get/access the environmental variables by running echo $variablename; however the rails application can still not see these environmental variables?

Comment: Spelling and case mismatch would be my first thought.  Are they in the correct environment that your Rails app is looking for (development, stage, production, etc.) and not just your local env?

Comment: You need to make sure that whatever shell or start script you use to start rails has sourced /etc/environment.  Not all shells do so by default.

Comment: @TimMee there are no spelling mistakes i can see. What do you mean by local env? Anything in /etc/environment should be global.

Comment: @KarenB I thought adding the environmental variables to /etc/environment means they automatically get sourced when the server turns on?

Comment: The OS does not manage processes' environments for them.  Ultimately, all user-level processes get started by a shell process, which sets its environment by reading various configuration files, and the child processes inherit that shell process's environment.  And not all shells are guaranteed to read /etc/environment.  So... no.

Comment: @KarenB Okay thank you, what would you suggest to be the best way to make the environmental variables visible to a user level process/rails server?

Comment: How are you starting rails?

Comment: @KarenB with puma and nginx as a http server.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/environment` is not automatically sourced by all shells in all login contexts.  To get the settings into the rails environment, there are a couple options.  The easiest is probably to modify (or create) the `.bashrc` (assuming the rails user's shell is `bash`, which is the Ubuntu default shell) in the home directory of the user rails runs as and add the following line:

```
source /etc/environment
```

If you want the variables to be available to all users on the system, you can create a file called `/etc/profile.d/environment.sh` (or something similar) and add the above line to that.

For either solution, log in again as the rails user and verify the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this gem for env variables:
https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv